# Telerik Raid Grid view in window application

Tags: telerik-grid

User can't check checkbox in Radgrid View.

Suppose a grid has three rows and each row has a checkbox.
When the second row is checked, we need to verify if the first row is checked too.

Comment: Please provide some code. Additionally, this isnt even a question

Comment: Yes, write your code, bring it here, and we can give you some suggestions.  That's what SO is for.